# Intersection does not take list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sets, intersection

The function `Intersection` takes a number of lists (sets) and finds their intersection. However, the precise input is `Intersection[{1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 3}]` and not `Intersection[{{1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 3}}]`.

This means I am having difficulty automatising my procedure using `Table`. For example, I wish to first construct `myInput=Table[i+j,{i,1,5},{j,1,8}]` and then `Intersection[myInput]`.

This does not work, and `Flatten` doesn't seem to be able to flatten at level `0`.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).

```
Intersection @@ {{1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 3}}
```

and

```
Apply[Intersection, {{1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 3}}]
```

are two different notations for the same.

Comment: Oh great, thanks! Kinda strange though, isn't it.

Comment: @LBogaardt Not at all.  When you get used to Mathematica, Apply will be one of the fundamental tools you will use every day.  [This is a nice tutorial that's worth a look.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html)

Comment: Well, I mean, it's a bit strange 'Intersection' doesn't just accept a list of lists immediately, or ask at what level you wish to intersect: Intersection[{{1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 3}}, 1] seems the most logical input to me.

Comment: @LBogaardt I guess it's because a set could have elements that are lists, and Apply solves the problem easily anyway.  Recent versions of Mathematica have specialized functions for many small tasks, such as `Total`, but older versions were more minimalist and you had to implement things by combining more primitive functions.  For example instead of `Total[a]` we used `Plus @@ a`.

Comment: @Szabolcs +1. One good technical reason for the introduction of `Total` is that `Apply` always unpacks. And in the past (before `Total` was introduced), there was no way around this.

Comment: @Leonid I agree that there are several reasons for `Total`, another one is being able to control whether to use compensated summation or not, and yet another one is an easy syntax to sum ("collapse") n-dimensional tensors along any direction.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, right, but my point was not to go into technicalities but just to note that the unpacking issue was totally unacceptable (while other things `Total` brought to the table are nice but not so vital, IMO).